# How to use numactl with slurm?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, slurm, numa, numactl

I have a cluster with many nodes. Each node has 32 cores divided into 4 numa nodes. The cluster is managed by slurm, which means I have to use srun or sbatch to run applications.
Because there are 4 numa nodes per node, so I run a scientific application with 4 MPI processes per node:

```
srun -N <num-nodes> -n <4 * num-nodes> -c 8
```

To improve performance, I want to use numactl to bind MPI processes to numa nodes. If I were using mpiexec, I would do something like this:

```
mpiexec -np 1 numactl --cpubind=0 --membind=0 <app> :
        -np 1 numactl --cpubind=1 --membind=1 <app> :
        -np 1 numactl --cpubind=2 --membind=2 <app> :
        -np 1 numactl --cpubind=3 --membind=3 <app>
```

But what should I do since I have to use slurm ?

Comment: there are two better options. Use `srun` to direct launch your application (assuming your MPI library has PMI(x) support)  or use the MPI command line to request a specific binding (this is implementation specific)

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Thank you for your answer. But in the second option, how do I use MPI command line while I'm using slurm?

Comment: since this is MPI implementation specific, which library (vendor & version) are you using?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I'm using mpich3.2.1

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet and slurm 15.08

Comment: SLURM seems to have its own way of binding processes to sockets/domains/cores. See [Support for Multi-core/Multi-thread Architectures](https://slurm.schedmd.com/mc_support.html).